# InDesign: Convert RGB to CMYK for clean gray colors

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, cmyk, color-conversion

When I convert gray color swatch from RGB to CMYK InDesign transmit that as a mix of C, M, Y, K. How can I convert that values to K only?

The goal is to get clean gray colors on print output. Another question I have, is it beneficial to use 100% Black with adjusting the 'Tint' option instead (for getting gray)?

Comment: Use proper color library that is designed to translate RGB to K only. Or when exporting files use job that change RGB to Black.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY, in my experience it's not possible to automatically convert swatches in InDesign to grayscale. I would manually create the gray swatches. It would be interesting to see how it's done! About using 100% Black tints (instead of RGB gray swatches?). Well, yes if it's CMYK Black. If it's RGB Black it's the same problem.

Comment: @Wolff Yeah, I meant manually but with the use of dedicated library. It's been a long time since I allowed RGB gray swatched in my files.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY, by "library" do you mean "ICC profile"? And I do agree that it would be easier to just avoid RGB gray when neutral grays are wanted. You can have a mix of CMYK and RGB swatches if you want and only convert RGB to correct CMYK on export and leave the grays untouched (*Preserve Numbers*).

Comment: @Wolff ICC would be a part of JOB for pdf (but I learned it's better <than by profile> to do it semi-manual in Acrobat). I meant library in color mode. Which need to be done by hand (but only once).

Answer (score 0):

You should set a profile that is set to change specific RGB range into K channel, otherwise you will the “dirty grey” when converting into CMYK.

If you are printing in office printers, many printer driver software allows you to create a custom profile. Turning off all the “vivid photo” options and setting the color management to “manual” would usually eliminate 75% of color problems.

On the other hand, if you are going to be sending it to a commercial printer, you should take into account that,

1. Printing machines add some paint in all channels;
2. Sometimes (as in very often) printers have their RIP set to add some paint in a different plate to compensate for that.

So, to conclude, there is no direct way to maintain the grey value when converting from RGB to CMYK, due to the above-mentioned factors.

Generally though, if you want to use grey, it would be wise to add it only in CMYK space.

Comment: The thing you say about "Printing machines add some paint in all channels" is only partly true. Digital printers, especially mid-low end, does this, but high-end digital print and offset print often preserves the chosen values. The RIP might *lower* the ink values to compensate for *dot gain*, but adding CMY ink to grays wouldn't be a nice thing to do as it ruins the work done by the designer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Indesign right now, but as I recall, one option is to turn the image into Grayscale, which will use only the K channel on the output.

I can be wrong though.

Comment: That's going to yield some awfully pale images ;)

Comment: But only on the K channel. If he needs contrast, he can adjust it later, or even use a real black ink. ;)